# Can I offer coupon codes for a paid app to be free at Google Play Store?

Tags: android

The last article I found about this was from 2012 and it says it wasnt possible. I tried searching Google for this, but I found some apps that offer coupons for other use.

So can I have a paid app on Google Play Store but have a limited amount of coupons that will enable coupon holders to get the app for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly nothing has changed since 2012, at least in that regard.
There is no way to give away your paid app for free (besides refunding of course, where google will still keep their 30% share).

The playstore lacks a lot in regards to promoting your app, even creating a trial version is way harder than it should be.

So if you really need coupons you will have to go with in-app purchases or a second app with beta invites, otherwise you are out of luck.